Logout a user in ckan2.10
How can I redirect logged-in user to the logout page using Ckan 2.10?
I tried to use Flask's make_response, and render_template, but the render_template, it managed to redirect to that page, but how can I redirect to a proper page with CSS on it?
Sorry I couldnt screenshot the sample.
The page redirected contains only textbox and text, without the actual CSS.
